# Why doesn't this formula for spherical capacitors in series apply in all cases?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

The capacitance for two [spherical capacitors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html) ([in series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Capacitors)) is$$
\large{C~=~\frac{4 \pi\epsilon_0}{\frac{1}{r_{\text{inner}}}+\frac{1}{r_{\text{outer}}}-\frac{2}{d}}}\,,$$
where:

- $r_{\text{inner}}$ is the radius of the inner sphere in each capacitor;
- $r_{\text{outer}}$ is the radius of the outer sphere in each capacitor;
- $d$ is the distance between the two spherical capacitors.

We were given this formula in class and told that it works for when inner spheres are earthed, but that it doesn't work when the outer spheres are earthed is earthed.

**Questions:**

1. Where did this formula come from?
2. Why doesn't this formula work when the outer spheres are earthed?

Comment: To avoid repetitions, maybe you could start by giving details on why you think it doesn’t work when the outer sphere is grounded?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero put d=b-a and that will not give the formula

Comment: but how is setting $d=b-a$ related to grounding the outer sphere?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero please see the formula. The distance between the spheres should be d= b-a either inner is grounded or outer

Comment: Sorry I don’t know what you’re asking.  The capacitance of this kind of arrangement is usually given as $C=k/(1/a-1/b)$ as per http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html. Can you please explain the physics that you are missing rather than the formula you want to obtain?  For instance, how did you obtain your origins expression?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero okay how this formula which you stated give the capacitance of spherical capacitors when outer is grounded?

Comment: Fixed up the question a bit, but please ensure that the edits are accurate.

Comment: BTW, the short answer's probably because the formula may assume that the outer spheres are internal to the combined (series) capacitor, so grounding an outer sphere would basically mean disrupting the combined capacitor's structure.  (But just glanced at it, so probably want to check that.)

Comment: @Nat The link you have inserted does not indicate that the capacitance is of the form given by the OP.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yup, it seems to be derived.  The capacitance for a spherical capacitor is as you noted above, and I'm guessing that there's two of those in-series.

Comment: @Nat Clearly I don't understand this question... :(

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It looks like a special case of the boxed equation on printed-page 40 of [this PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02t-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2005/lecture-notes/chap5capacitance.pdf).  Dunno if that's precisely what it is, though the derivation would seem similar; basically looks like two spherical capacitors hooked up in series.

Comment: Hah, opps... looks like I typo'd the $2$ into the wrong part of the fraction!  There we go.  =P

Comment: @Nat how did you deduce this was a problem with caps in series?  The original posting does not suggests this in any way.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm sorry I should have posted that the capacitors Are in series.

Comment: @Nat  I'm sorry I should have posted that the capacitors Are in series.